# last processed item in ItemWriter spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I want to get the last processed item in ItemWriter and write one of the string value of the item in execution context , I am using chunks writes. Since it is chunk write , so write method would be called multiple times , how do I go about this?

Here is my writer:

```
@Component
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyDbEntity>{


    private JobExecution jobExecution;


    @BeforeStep
    public void initWriter(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();

    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyDbEntity> items) throws Exception {



    }
```

Comment: Where will you read the information from the execution context? In the next step? Or at the end of the job? This important to know because it may influence the design of the solution to your problem.

Comment: This would be at the end of job

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the last processed item in ItemWriter and write one of the string value of the item in execution context

Let's say your `MyDbEntity` provides a getter `getData` for the data you want to write in the execution context. A simple way to do it is to write the data with same key for each item. This will erase the data of the previous item and when the step is finished, the data of the last item will be the one present in the execution context. Something like:

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends MyDbEntity> items) throws Exception {
    for(MyDbEntity item: items) {
        // write item where needed
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("data", item.getData());
    }
}
```

The job execution will be persisted after the step is completed (successfully or not) and you can get access to the data of the last item from the execution context.

Hope this helps.